# Segmentation output image of network is similar to the input image

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been working on a transformer-UNet hybrid that will perform semantic segmentation on a lung CT scan to identify tumours.

`Sample input`

[image: Sample input]

`Sample output`

[image: sample output]

`Network output`

[image: network output]]

[transUNet functional model](https://pastebin.com/EmnqhKjK)

[patch generator and patch encoder](https://pastebin.com/6vwtQJdd)

[Cascaded UpSampler](https://pastebin.com/W1fWqidE)

[transformer encoder](https://pastebin.com/z47NXstD)

I am not entirely sure why this happening. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: just FYI SO usually encourages people post code directly to the site, so that changes can be recorded in case the links break or the original question changes

Comment: Did you try using a sigmoid activation function in the last Conv2D layer of the transUNet model ?

Comment: @Droidux I have changed the activation in the final layer to sigmoid, but the issue still persists.

Comment: What is the range of pixel values in the output image you displayed ?

Comment: 0. - 1. (float values) @Droidux

Comment: How are they distributed ? If they are all very low, maybe what you have could be a visualization problem. Apart from that, I don't see where the problem could come from...maybe underfitting, but really not shure...

Comment: @Droidux the values are pretty high actually. I took a random sample and check their mean and median. The measures were 0.83 & 0.97 for the input sample, while it was 0.99 and 1 for output sample.

Comment: Maybe your output is simply the probability of the healthy class ?